# Does the Seowon's 4 science count as an adjacency bonus?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

The Campus district receives science adjacency bonuses for mountains, other districts, and rainforests.

Instead, the Seowon, Korea's replacement, receives base 4 science, -1 for each adjacent district, and +1 for each adjacent Government Plaza. Do any of these count as an adjacency bonus with respect to things that boost science adjacency bonuses?

- Natural Philosophy policy: +100% Campus science adjacency
- Heartbeat of Steam dedication: Campus science adjacency provides production

Comment: I was told by my friend in a game last night that it was, but I can't confirm 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at least the base 4 science and -1 from the capital district are counted for the Heartbeat of Steam dedication as you can see from this screenshot.

[image: Seowon with Heartbeat of Steam]

**Edit:** Continuing in the same game, I just picked up the Rationalism policy which increases science from Campus buildings by +50% if the city has 10 population and +50% if the adjacency bonus is at least 3, and I received both on the district above.

Comment: Can confirm. Your edit is a bit confusing though. Rationalism's bonus only applies to the district buildings, as usual, and not to the seowon's base science itself.

Comment: @Junuxx Hopefully my edit clarifies that it does indeed count as an adjacency bonus.